# Why does rails new say template not loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why does

```
$ rails _3.2.0_ new linker -dmysql -T
```

return:

```
The template [/home/durrantm/linker/template] could not be loaded.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a space between the -d option and the value, so instead of:

```
$ rails _3.2.0_ new linker -dmysql -T
```

use

```
$ rails _3.2.0_ new linker -d mysql -T
```